# Procesador de contexto para plantillas | ValueError - Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, login, diccionarios

Muy buenas amigos, tengo mi procesador de contexto personalizado, para que se pueda ocupar en todas las plantillas de mi proyecto django en forma de variable:

```
{{ u_model }}
```

Este es mi procesador de contexto:

**proccesors.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(redirect_field_name='login')
def ctx_dict(request):
    u_model = Model.objects.all().filter(user=request.user)
    ctx = {
        'u_model':u_model, 
    }
    return ctx
```

Esta añadido en settings como debe de ser:

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'my_app.proccesors.ctx_dict',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**plantilla.html**

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    {% for x in u_model %}
        {{ x.atributo }}  # Es un campo de mi modelo Model
    {% endfor  %}
{% else %}
     No logueado
{% endif %}
```

Todo funciona correctamente cuando el usuario esta logueado, pero cuando cierra su sesión me aparaece el siguiente error:

> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 1 is required

Entonces no se a que se deba. Muchas gracias amigos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def ctx_dict(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        u_model = Model.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        ctx = {
              'u_model':u_model, 
        }
    else:
       ctx = {}
return ctx
```

hazlo así, quita el decorador ya que dentro validas si tiene login o no, al `.all()` solo se usa si vas a devolver todos los registros si usas `.filter()` no hace falta.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que creo que está ocurriendo es que, no le das valor a `u_model` en el caso de que el usuario no esté logueado. En ese caso le envías un diccionario con clave pero sin valor. De ahí el error.

Hay varias formas de solucionarlo, por ejemplo verificar antes que el usuario está logueado.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(redirect_field_name='login')
def ctx_dict(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        u_model = Model.objects.all().filter(user=request.user)
        ctx = {
            'u_model':u_model, 
             }
    else:
        ctx = {}
    return ctx
```

Comment: Que tal ya había intentando hacer eso @Cecilio_Alonso pero me aparece este error amigo: `TypeError - 'bool' object is not callable`

Comment: Prueba a quitar los paréntesis y dejar la condicional tal que if request.user.is_autheticated:

Comment: Eso del parentesis si funciona hermano, gracias, pero me sigue mostrando el mismo error: `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 1 is required`

Comment: Prueba a poner en el else: ctx = {'u_model': 'prueba'} para comprobar si en el caso de no estar logueado pasa por ahí. Creo que con que tenga un valor el diccionar será suficiente. Dime por favor, que resultado te muestra en este caso. De todos modos, ¿en el error te detalla en que linea falla? por si estamos fijandonos en el sitio equivocado.

Comment: Gracias viejo si funciono, saludos!